# Python is not plotting lines correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, behavior

In the following code, "plot" is not drawing the lines correctly: the lines don´t pass precisely by all of my points. Why? What am I doing wrong? I use Microsoft Visual Studio with Python 3.7 (64 bits). I open the image with Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0 (64 bits), expand it 20 times (because my project needs big images), and then I get something like the attached image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplpp

RA = [2.007128649, 4.71238898, 0.916297857, 2.007128649]
Dec = [-1.439896633, -1.439896633, -1.483529864, -1.483529864]

x = []
y = []

num = 100

for i in range(0, 4, 2):
    if (RA[i] == RA[i + 1]):
        alfa = RA[i]
        for t in range(0, num + 1, 1):
            delta = Dec[i] + (Dec[i + 1] - Dec[i]) * (t / num)
            x.append((np.pi/2 + delta) * np.cos(alfa))
            y.append((np.pi/2 + delta) * np.sin(alfa))    
    elif (Dec[i] == Dec[i + 1]):
        delta = Dec[i]
        if (RA[i + 1] - RA[i] <= -np.pi):
            var_alfa = RA[i + 1] - RA[i] + 2*np.pi
        elif (RA[i + 1] - RA[i] >= np.pi):
            var_alfa = RA[i + 1] - RA[i] - 2*np.pi
        else:
            var_alfa = RA[i + 1] - RA[i]
        for t in range(0, num + 1, 1):
            alfa = RA[i] + var_alfa * (t / num)
            x.append((np.pi/2.0 + delta) * np.cos(alfa))
            y.append((np.pi/2.0 + delta) * np.sin(alfa))

mplpp.scatter(x, y, color = 'r', s = 0.005)
mplpp.plot(x, y, color = 'g', linewidth = 0.1)
mplpp.fill(x, y, color = 'b', linewidth = 0.1, fill = False)

mplpp.axis('off')
mplpp.axis('equal')

mplpp.savefig('image.ps', transparent = True, dpi = 100)

print("Done...")
```

["fill" seems to be more accurate than "plot", but why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8xcW.png)

Comment: I think this is because `scatter` is snapping the markers to the nearest pixel.  Probably `fill` is as well, though I'm not sure.  If you increase your dpi this will be less noticeable.

Comment: When dpi = 1200, for example, I see the same problem :(

Comment: You are saving as a ps, so `dpi` in the save argument doesn't have any effect.  Save as a png then I cannot see the effect with MPL. 3.1.  I get a very small effect if I save in postscript, but its pretty small.  You are making tiny markers and lines, so I wouldn't be shocked if there aren't some roundoff problems

Comment: I need a vectorial image, indeed. But, if "fill" or a "png" are not affected by this roundoff, why is "plot" affected? It looks like a bug :/

Comment: You can submit a bug report, but I'd also check that its not just a bug in your postscript renderer.  Again, I do get a difference between the two lines, but it is far smaller than yours.  The fill and plot objects are rendered quite differently in postscript, I think so small differences in how a postscript renderer does `fill` versus `stroke` could cause small differences.